# Join window server 2019 standard into Windows 2012 R2 DC with domain functional level windows 2003?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019

We are planning to upgrade our old server from windows 2008 standard to windows 2019 standard.

We have 4 DCs - 2 running on windows 2012 R2 and 2 running windows 2008 R2 with domain functional level 2003.

We would like to ask if we install a new windows 2019 standard (not DC) can we join into the domain with domain functional level 2003?

Comment: AFAIK, yes you can join a Windows Server 2019 computer to the domain with a DFL/FFL of 2003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link to Microsoft's [Forest and Domain Functional Levels](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/active-directory-functional-levels) doc if you want all the details about DFL/FFL levels.

The important bit relating to your question is this (emphasis, mine):

> Functional levels determine the available Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS) domain or forest capabilities. They also determine which Windows Server operating systems you can run on domain controllers in the domain or forest. However, **functional levels do not affect which operating systems you can run on workstations and member servers** that are joined to the domain or forest.

So in short, yes. You should have no problems adding a Server 2019 member server to a 2003 DFL/FFL domain/forest.